# password salt datatype

Tags: database, passwords, schema

I have the password stored as char(128) for sha512. And as far as i read that should be the accurate data type for it. However i am not sure about the datatype and the length to use for password salt. Since it is a random number should i use varchar(255) or is there a binary or something else to use?

And in the database only two colunms are required correct?
Password _hash
Password_salt

We are not storing anything else for password authentication apart from the username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `BINARY(64)` (or so) column.

The salt should be a moderately long cryptographically secure sequence of random *bytes*.
Do not limit yourself to ASCII characters.

Comment: I don't know how important it is that the salt be cryptographically secure, but you might as well.

Comment: `IMAGE` doesn't have a length.

Comment: Forgot to mention i am using MySQL, could not see an image type.

Comment: As i write in above post, where does crypto come in to scene? My unique salt = Maryhadalittlefox so I am storing this in the DB correct? OR am i hashing this also?

Comment: @Mdillion: That's wrong.  As I said, the salt should be a _random_ sequence of bytes, **and must be different for each user**.  When creating a user account, you need to generate a random salt for that user.

Comment: @SLaks, so if the salt is different than for each user then Mdillion needs a separate field to store it, right?  Just clarifying since you didn't say it specifically in your answer.

Comment: @Samuel: Yes.  It would still be possible to store it along with the hash as Marcelo mentioned, but I don't think that's worth it.

Comment: @Slaks, if you don't store it, then how do you validate the user entered the correct password on return? You need to know the same random salt to recalculate the same resulting hash..?

Comment: @Samuel: I meant that you could intersperse the salt bytes with the hash bytes.

Comment: @Slaks, that's a different approach I hadn't thought of.  However, if someone knew how the salt was interspersed then they can extract the hash easily and it's less secure than applying the salt before hashing.  Right?

Comment: @Samuel: Correct.  It's just security through obscurity.  It wasn't my idea.